# add_rewrite_rule is not taking effect in Wordpress? .htaccess file doesn't update

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have tried all day to get my own rewrite to work in wordpress, but I simply can't get anything to work. I've tried so many different ways but thing is nothing updates in the .htaccess file so I am not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point. This for example I found at the wordpress manual I've tried, but it doesn't work. https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule. I heard that you need to flush the rewrite, so I tried adding flush_rewrite_rules(); to the functions.php file too, but it doesn't do any difference. Also I update the wordpress permalinks to get a refresh that way too. But it still doesn't happen anything in the .htaccess file. So what do I do? By the way, I'm using a web hotel server host service so I can't change any "deep" server settings by myself really.

I am using the WP Fastest Cache plugin, which shows a lot in the .htaccess file. I started thinking if that would interfere, but I think not. Have no idea what to do, I really want to make my links work, where I have custom templates with $_GET[''] parameters to nice looking urls. Thing is I only need it to work to start going, as it is now, nothing happens whatever I do. simplest add_rewrite_rule doesn't affect anything. I am sure the .htaccess is in the site root folder, and that I am editing the correct functions.php file.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

The .htaccess file (which is completly generated, but with no tracks of my functions rewrite).

```
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /storage/content/64/117764/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache
# BEGIN GzipWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype font/ttf font/eot font/otf
</IfModule>
# END GzipWpFastestCache
# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Expires "max-age=2592000, public"
Header unset ETag
Header set Connection keep-alive
FileETag None
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN mywebsite
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

#ENDjapgoi
```

Comment: wordpress internal rewrite rules do not end up in `.htaccess`, they end up in the global `$wp_rewrite` array to be processed by wordpress. `.htaccess` is for external rewrite rules processed by your server. use https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/ for checking instead.

Comment: The rules are saved in the database and not needed to be added to the .htaccess file. I would say to deactivate all your plugins and/or switch theme then try to see if it works.. Also try the `pagename` instead `index.php?pagename=$matches[1]` e.g `sample-page`

Answer (score 3):

As someone else suggested, I reactivated my theme and it started working!